# WebKit, embedding, dynamic resources

Tags: webkit

I assume you can embed WebKit into another desktop app and send a string to it, say:

```
<html>Hello world!</html>
```

and it will display it inside the window.

My question is, how do I send an image to it, if I have its compressed representation (JPEG dump) loaded in memory? E.g.:

```
unsigned char image[] = {123, 183, 234, ... };
```

Related question, what happens if I write:

```
<html><img src="URL"></html>
```

at the URL end, there has to be web server, OK - but is there a way to display an image in WebKit without a web server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use file or Data URIs,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme